# How to add to the value of a dictionary (and not to update it) in a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:

```
diction = {}

for i in range (5):
    key = "key"
    diction[key] = {str(i)}
print (diction)
```

The printed result, obviously, would be this:

```
{'key': {'4'}}.
```

How can I change the code so I can have this as the output:

```
{'key': {'0','1','2','3','4'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a value to a set, you should use the `.add` method. For the initial case (i=1), you should also check if the key has been set in the dictionary so you don't add to an inexistent set and get an error:

Accordingly, your new code would be:

```
diction = {}

for i in range (5):
    key = "key"
    if key not in diction:
        diction[key] = {i}
    else:
        diction[key].add(i)
```

The result of :

```
print (diction)
```

is now

```
{'key': {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the "'dict' object has no attribute 'add'" error.

Comment: Did you make sure to access the correct key before adding to the set inside the dictionary? `diction[key].add(str(i))` would add to set inside the dictionary while `diction.add(str(i))` would attempt to add directly to the dictionary, which will yield the error you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

`.add()` to the set?

```
diction = {'key': set()}

for i in range(5):
    diction['key'].add(str(i))

print(diction['key'])
```

---

**EDIT**:

```
diction = {}

for i in range(5):
    k = 'key'+str(i*2)
    if not k in diction:
        diction[k] = set()
    
    diction[k].add(str(i))

print(diction)
```

A list comprehension should be WAY better:

```
diction = {'key': set(map(str,range(5)))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What if the Key also in not pre-decided? Say the key would be i*2 (which means that we would have for keys and for values)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the two most common ways to do this in Python is by using either the `dict.setdefault()` method or the `collections.defaultdict` dictionary subclass.

Both make it easy to modify the value of existing entries without checking to see if it's the first time the key has been seen. Below are examples of doing it both ways.

#### `setdefault()`:

```
diction = {}

for i in range (5):
    key = "key"
    diction.setdefault(key, set()).add(str(i))

print(diction)
```

#### `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

diction = defaultdict(set)

for i in range (5):
    key = "key"
    diction[key].add(str(i))

print(diction)
```